# Reporting Services Text Case

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is there a way in Reporting Services of managing the case of text when rendering a report.

The data in the database has a

> RANDOM mixtures of CAPS

and on the reports they would like to see

> Random mixtures of caps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An expression like this should do the trick:

```
=UCase(left(Fields!Name.Value, 1)) + strconv(Mid(Fields!Name.Value, 2), vbLowerCase)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use an expression for this, I just don't know if there's an out of the box function available to perform changes to the case. You can get a list of all string functions in the expression window.

If there is no such function, you can still use [embedded code](http://odetocode.com/articles/130.aspx) to do the trick.

Comment: Was hoping there was an internal function for this; there is upper and lower case. I could manipulate the strings manually a fairly complex (for my reports anyway) expression I guess